# MapPoint 2006 - can I have custom maps?

Tags: map-point

I have Microsoft MapPoint 2006 installed as a part of a larger system for home/social care planning. The maps and the address information points are quite incomplete and I would like to roll out my own layers that are way better.

Can anyone explain how to do this or perhaps point to where I can find the information on the subject?

Comment: The newer version will have a better address database and more functionality - it is still a relatively cheap mapping tool. 60 day trial of MapPoint 2011 is here - http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/freetrial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the slow reply. @Mapperz is essentially correct. MapPoint does not support custom basemaps or upgrading of the underlying basemaps. Instead you have to install the latest version (there is some logic to this as the bulk of the disk space is map data and the bulk of the cost is in sub-licensing costs).

You asked in late 2011 so MapPoint 2011 would have been the latest version. MapPoint 2013 is now the latest version, but Microsoft have announced a 'sun setting' of the Streets&Trips / MapPoint range and it will only be available until the end of December. Support continues until summer 2015.